# Notification setFullScreenIntent stops functioning after toggling notification channel off and on

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a notification that gets displayed when I have an incoming VOIP call.

I have correctly set `setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)` and have the manifest permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />`

Everything works perfectly fine under normal circumstances.  If the phone screen is OFF when an incoming call comes in, the full screen intent triggers and opens up my activity where they can answer the call.

However...

If a user long presses on the notification, or goes into the apps notification settings and toggles the notification channel OFF and then back ON the full screen pending intent stops functioning until the app is uninstalled/reinstalled.

All the other code is running. The phone is ringing and the notification is in the tray.  It just will not launch the full screen pending intent anymore.

I've seen it on Android 8.1 and Android 10.0 (what I have available) from 2 different manufacturers.

I haven't figured out any other way around this.  Does anyone know what is going on? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I've been able to prove this is happening to some users by having logging showing me the channel is turned off when they report problems, but if they toggle it off/on immediately (sometimes even unaware) I can't report on that since I don't know...  If there was a way to prove this had happened, that would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to this problems is indicated in this answer

[Android O - turn off notification channel and then turn on, the importance level always reset to medium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185818/android-o-turn-off-notification-channel-and-then-turn-on-the-importance-level)

The importance level is getting reset, and with the incorrect importance level, the full screen pending intent is no longer configured properly.

While I no longer work on this app to confirm the problem and solution, I believe checking the importance level for the incorrect value to detect the problem will work.

Since we can't modify channels once created there are two options.

1. Alerting the user to problem so they can uninstall/reinstall the app which will correct the wrong importance level.
2. You may be able to delete the channel and recreate it.  You can't change settings when you do this, but it might revert to original settings.  IF this doesn't work though, you could delete the channel, and create a new one with an ever incrementing ID which you manage through something like shared preferences.

Hopefully this gets fixed in a future version of the OS